# Change the format of datepicker and make the field read only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm new at jquery and the date picker. How will I change the format to YYYY-MM-DD and not allow user to type in the field but only select date? I tried everything and I can't seem to get it to work. Thank you all in advance

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


<script>
$(function() {
$( ".from" ).datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 2,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( ".to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
}
});
$( ".to" ).datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 2,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( ".from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
}
});
});
</script>

<body>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" class="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" class="to">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `readonly` attribute. Add `cursor: text` to the css to make it look normal.

```
<input type="text" class="from" readonly>
```

and

```
input[readonly]{ cursor: text }
```

To get the `YYYY-MM-DD` date format, use the option

```
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hn01z90v/

Comment: What about changing the date format to YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: @yawyaw Use `dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',` I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" class="from"/>
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" class="to" readonly='true' />
</body>



$( ".to" ).datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 2,
dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
})
```

Comment: What about changing the date format to YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: $( ".to" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: '
YYYY-MM-DD' });

Comment: where do I add that? can you paste the original code with that in there? Thanks

Comment: $( ".to" ).datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 2,
dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
})